# Access childnodes' children in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do i access child nodes of a child node in javascript?
I need to target the img inside of each li and get its width and height.
I want to do this without using jquery. Just pure javascript.

```
<ul id="imagesUL">
<li>
   <h3>title</h3>
   <img src="someURL" />
</li>
</ul>


var lis = document.getElementById("imagesUL").childNodes;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is with the `querySelectorAll` function, if you can guarantee that it will be available (if you are designing a site for mobile browsers, for instance).

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('#imagesUL li img');
```

If you can't guarantee that, however, you'll have to do the loop yourself:

```
var = lis = document.getElementById("imagesUL").childNodes,
      imgs = [],
      i, j;

for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < lis[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
        if (lis[i].childNodes[j].nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
            imgs.push(lis[i].childNodes[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above snippet of code is an excellent argument for using a library like jQuery to preserve your sanity.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var children = document.getElementById('imagesUL').children;
var grandChildren = [];
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
    var child = children[i];
    for (var c = 0; c < child.children.length; c++)
        grandChildren.push(child.children[c]);
}
```

`grandChildren` contains all childrens' children.

Libraries like jQuery and UnderscoreJS make this easier to write in a more declarative way.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a second parameter to the `$()` function to specify a scope in which to search for the images:

```
var lis = $('#imagesUL').children();
var images = $('img', lis)
images.each(function() {
    var width = $(this).attr('width');
    // ...
});
```

Comment: how would you do something similar with just javascript?